# Trying to make a hash cracking command using hashes.org api, error Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'result'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code goes as follows:

```
    @commands.command(name='crackhash', aliases = ['hashcrack'])
    async def hashcracking(self, ctx, query):
        url = "https://hashes.org/api.php?key=" + hashapi_key + ".&query=" + query
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                r = await response.json(content_type=None)
                embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.purple(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                                    title=f"Hash Cracking")
                member = ctx.message.author
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
                embed.add_field(name=f"Status", value={r['status']}, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"{query}", value="Algorithm: " + [r][0]['result'][query]['algoritm]'], inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Plaintext", value={r[0]['result'][query]['plain']}, inline=False)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Here's an example of the API: https://hashes.org/api.php?key=3Ak6W7ytyIo3GS0mG3cUpARnpCVbnd&query=9ede947a76b6af18f51996d0817ac496

If someone could help with this that would be great because to be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: Perhaps if the query failed (i.e. `"status"` is something other than `"success"`), then there is no `"result"` field?

Comment: Printing `r` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
embed.add_field(name=f"{query}", value="Algorithm: " + [r['result'][query]['algorithm'], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name=f"Plaintext", value={r['result'][query]['plain']}, inline=False)
```

Comment: gives me this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'algorithm'

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own code.
Changed it to this:

```
    @commands.command(name='crackhash', aliases = ['hashcrack'])
    async def hashcracking(self, ctx, query):
        url = "https://hashes.org/api.php?key=" + hashapi_key + "&query=" + query
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                str(query)
                r = await response.json(content_type=None)
                embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.purple(), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                                    title=f"Hash Cracking")
                status = (f"{r['status']}")
                status.capitalize()
                member = ctx.message.author
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
                embed.add_field(name=f"Status", value=status, inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Algorithm", value=f"{r['result'][query]['algorithm']}", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name=f"Plaintext", value=f"{r['result'][query]['plain']}", inline=False)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Thanks for the help though!